# ¿Es recomendable corregir la ortografía de las preguntas?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, revisiones

Tengo una duda y me gustaría consultarla aquí en Meta.

Son varias las veces en las que me encuentro preguntas en este foro con muchísimas faltas de ortografía, o sin comas, acentos, o mayúsculas.

Hoy me puse a corregir unas pocas que encontré. No tengo reputación suficiente, así que por lo que vi, se envían a una "cola de revisión".

Mi pregunta es: ¿es recomendable corregir la ortografía de las preguntas? Lo pregunto porque, aunque a nivel de información no añade nada, sí mejora la calidad de la pregunta, y la hace más entendible.

¡Gracias!

Comment: **En mi opinion** es una buena razón para editar las preguntas. Pues como dices, mejoras su calidad. Aunque en información no añade nada.

Comment: Y sí, se envian a una cola de revisión hasta que tengas más de 2000 de reputación

Comment: Y te aclaro, que esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: Falta una mayúscula a tu primera palabra ;-)

Comment: ¡Gracias por las explicaciones! Y, ahora mismo corrijo la mayúscula, gracias. ;)

Comment: Por supuesto que se debe. No se cómo esté SO en Inglés ahora, pero hace un tiempo eran muy estrictos con eso. Quitaban todos los saludos (*hola*, *qué tal*...), *tengo un problema*, *gracias de antemano*, *estoy tomando un curso*, *ayudenme con*, etc. La cuestión es que la pregunta (y respuestas) finalmente queda impersonal y consisa al problema.

Comment: Pues yo me arto de rechazar correcciones ortográficas, pues a veces son tan livianas que me da pena aceptarlas.  Quizás es un solo cambio y para mi eso no mejora la pregunta, aunque si la ortografia, claro. Estoy de acuerdo con que son errores, pero me ha parecido ver casos de usuarios que sólo se dedican a eso, como si fueran linguístas en lugar de programadores. Yo optaria por no aceptarlos, y cuando tengan la suficiente reputación para hacerlo sin revisión pues entonces adelante, pero antes me parece que solo quieren sacar puntos (algunos, no todos, eh! que nadie se ofenda!)

Comment: @masterguru los puntos por edición tienen limite y pasado cierto puntaje, dejas de recibirlos. No hay razón como "no mereces los puntos" como para denegar una buena edición.

Comment: @Excorpion Vale, pensaba que eso pasaba cuando ya podias ver las colas de edicion. Pues bueno, tendré que haceros caso y permitir esas correcciones, venga, no voy a ser siempre el malo :-)  Ah, no, no, no eran "buenas ediciones", esas vale, pero si arreglan dos y se dejan tres más para mi no lo son aunque mejoren "algo" el tema.

Comment: ¡Gracias por estas explicaciones! En mi caso, cuando edito una pregunta/respuesta, intento fijarme bastante para no dejarme ninguna falta y hacer la pregunta más entendible. Creo que así, como comentaba @aeportugal, son más propensas a recibir respuesta o a que más gente las lea enteras.

Comment: @masterguru Y aunque lo hagan por sacar puntos, el caso es que mejora el aspecto del sitio. Somos programadores, nos ganamos la vida *escribiendo*. Qué menos que escribir de manera al menos *casi* correcta, no? A mi me resulta mucho más fácil leer, y sobre todo entender, una pregunta si está bien escrita que si no.

Comment: @Benito-B Sí, claro que sí, pero si lo hacen que lo hagan bien del todo. No por corregir 1 falta ortográfica y dejarse 5 merecen que les aprobemos su corrección. Mejor que sepan que no lo han hecho bien del todo creo yo.  Hay muchos casos dispares, desde los que solo corrigen ortografia pero no ven el código que sigue escondido a otros casos que también son de cajón.  Esas las rechazo y edito por mi cuenta.

Comment: @Benito-B Hay uno, por ejemplo, que me hace cierta gracia, pues se dedica a poner los tres acentos graves y la etiqueta del lenguage de programación en el código, que ha sido previamente identado mediante el botón de código por el OP, y al hacerlo no se da cuenta que el código ha pasado a moverse 4 espacios a la derecha porque no ha quitado la identación.  Y solo hace eso, no corrige faltas, no revisa etiquetas, nada, solo eso. ¿Pues que debo hacer? ¿Lo apruebo?

Comment: Perdón, me salí del tema, aquí estamos hablando de las faltas ortográficas. Mis disculpas.

Comment: @masterguru eso no es una corrección ortografica (aunque creo que ya te diste cuenta), en ese caso en mi opinión debe rechazarse o dejar la revisión a otro. Eso por que con su edición está desmejorando la pregunta.

Comment: Yo corrijo las faltas ortográficas porque hacen las preguntas bastante enredadas. De pronto encuentro párrafos de más de 6 renglones y sin puntos o comas, y con palabras llenas de mayúsculas. Es decir, es cansado para leer.
Mi propósito al corregirlas, es hacerlas fácilmente entendibles para los que las lean en el presente o en el futuro. Además, supongo que esto reduciría la cantidad de preguntas duplicadas.

Comment: Algo que me he dado cuenta en mi vida leyendo literatura y filosofía en español, es que los malditos acentos y demás signos de puntuación, realmente ayudan a que la lectura sea fluida. A veces uno está acostumbrado a ver tal palabra con acento, y, al verla, no pierde su tiempo "sientiendo" un, "de niño me dijeron que esa palabra lleva acento en la a".
Es decir, lo que sea con tal de que la pregunta sea "la misma" pero más para el lector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si, puedes corregir las preguntas que quieras, mientras sigas "el código de edición"... no hay cosa como tal, pero son reglas básicas.

- La edición debe mejorar la publicación: Una corrección de ortografía si lo hace.
- No debes interrumpir en la intención del autor
- No realizar cambios ni correcciones al código: Aunque la identación por mi parte la permito por que a veces la visualización importa.
- No tratar de responder durante la edición. (hay gente que lo ha hecho)

Comment: Estoy en desacuerdo con la excepción al tercer punto. La identación es importante en (al menos) Python. Si corriges la identanción, podrías estar corrigiendo la causa de un error presente o futuro, y por lo tanto solucionando el problema del OP editando su pregunta. Tu excepción solo aplicaría en lenguajes de programación donde la identación no importa.

Comment: Siempre ha habido debate en el tema de la identación.. al menos siempre llegamos a ese consenso todos.

Comment: Gracias por las explicaciones, lo tendré en cuenta a partir de ahora.

Comment: Me parece que no se debe corregir la indentacion de un código del cual no se vaya a participar en la respuesta; por ejemplo si yo no se de PYTHON y no me interesa participar de la respuesta o comentarios de dicha pregunta no debería tocar el código y su indentacion ...

Comment: Se debe poder editar código solo para propósitos de visualización, sin hacer cambios a la sintaxis (Python es otro debate). He tenido casos de largas consultas SQL en una sola línea y pasan días y nadie voltea a ver la pregunta. La edito, le pongo sus saltos de línea e indentación, inmediatamente ha generado respuestas; incluso en más de una ocasión el OP ha comentado que al ordenar el código vio su error.

Comment: Personalmente, cuando el código está hecho unos zorros, sobretodo en html, javascript o php, que es lo que más o menos sé tocar, lo paso por el tidy del jsfidlle y se lo cambio en la pregunta, pues si se ve bien gana respuestas, como dice @aeportugal

Comment: @masterguru entiendo que el snippet interno de SOes tiene un formateador de HTML, CSS y JS

Comment: @JheymanMejia Pues ni me habia fijado, gracias, lo acabo de ver (botón Ordenar)... aunque el jsfiddle me marca errores de sintaxis que me ayudan a arreglar errores tipográficos muy facilmente cuando alguien pregunta y son typos.

Answer (score 1):

Mi opinión es que si es recomendable.

En mis dos trabajos más recientes he tenido que escribir en inglés y en castellano cambiando entre estos como si nada; y, para ser sincero, encuentro que el castellano tiene muchas reglas que, en lugar de aclarar, parecen más tramites que otra cosa, ya que hay mucho de lo que se puede inferir.

Por ejemplo, acentos, tildes, puntos al final de una numeración, espacios entre rayas largas, etc. El inglés es más anárquico (aunque tenga los mismos símbolos, como que la "cultura ortográfica" es un poco difernte), y el español parece más burocrático, y, a querer y no, esto afecta a la percepción del que escribe y del que lee.

Digo esto porque, gracias a este cambio entre lenguajes, me percato que el castellano, cuando (al menos para mi) falta a su gramática, aunque sea en un acento o una mayúscula, mi cerebro se tarda uno o dos segundos en procesar la pregunta, porque pienso, "Caray; esta palabra debería de llevar acento", o, "Quizás sea mejor poner esto entre un guíon largo ya que es una aclaración no indispensable".

Por esto siento que si es recomendable corregir cada error ortográfico. **No solo porque el error haga opaca a la respuesta, sino porque ayuda al lector para que no se fije en nimiedades que el lenguaje ya le impuso y a los que está acostumbrado a ver**.

Pero esto es como un comentario personal. No sé como otros lidien leyendo preguntas claras, pero con faltas de ortografía.

Por otro lado, me parece que es un poco obvio que, si la pregunta esta mal escrita, es buena idea cambiar la presentación más no el sentido de la publicación.

Aquí mi asunto sería el de motivar a los que escriben las preguntas, a mejorar la calidad de su publicación. Quizás, además del cambio, habría que hacerle saber que este fue hecho con tal de apoyarlo a él, al sitio, y a los lectores.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por esta gran respuesta! Opino exactamente como tú, tanto en lo referente a la respuesta cómo a los comentarios que has puesto. Creo que la buena ortografía ayuda a entender mejor la pregunta y a centrarse más en el sentido, evitando así perder tiempo pensando "esto no se escribe así". ¡Gracias por responder!