# ¿Debería haber más exigencia gramatical y ortográfica?

Tags: discusión

Es particularmente preocupante la cantidad de preguntas mal formuladas, faltas de ortografía constantes, de puntuación y de acentuación principalmente.

Entiendo que el cometido del foro no es, por supuesto, el lenguaje. Sin embargo considero que para mantener un estándar de calidad en el mismo, es necesario establecer estas normas mínimas a fin de garantizar la subsistencia del sitio.

¿Hasta qué punto podemos ser estrictos con ello? Entendiendo que es un foro en un lenguaje que tiene unas reglas concretas.

Comment: Aclarar que [es.so] **no es  un foro**. Por lo demás estoy de acuerdo con tu apreciación: hay muchas faltas ortográficas y gramaticales. En cuanto a tu pregunta, siempre está la opción de editar la pregunta/respuesta para mejorar su redacción y la otrografía y/o gramática. Sin embargo, si ya de por sí cuesta que muchos formulen una pregunta medianamente aceptable, imagina si añadimos más rigidez con el uso del lenguaje. Adicionalmente, hay que tomar en cuenta modismos o regionalismos, que en según la zona pueden ser de uso común o una total aberración de la lengua. Saludos

Comment: Es un signo de los tiempos, digo yo. Generaciones que ya no leen, solo miran videos. Sin lectura, no hay escritura ni capacidad expresiva más allá de gruñidos y resoplidos.

Comment: Relacionado [¿Es recomendable corregir la ortografía de las preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5349/es-recomendable-corregir-la-ortograf%c3%ada-de-las-preguntas)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, sin embargo no deja de irritarme entrar en SOes precisamente por la poca seriedad que exuda. Y veo una lástima que uno de los pocos sitios en nuestra lengua quede en esta condición.

Comment: Efectivamente está relacionado, pero no igual. Mientras que en la pregunta que indicas se discute sobre "corregir la ortografía" yo me centro en discutir si se podría exigir.

Comment: Me encantaría que en este sitio haya más exigencias en cuanto a redacción (te lo dice alguien que la mayor parte de sus ediciones consistieron en correcciones ortográficas y gramaticales, ya que pareciera que hasta desconocen que las comas existen). Pero... La idea principal del sitio es la de redactar preguntas acerca de programación. Además, si ni siquiera son capaces de adjuntar un ejemplo mínimo verificable de su problema (o no logramos convencerlos), mucho menos podremos convencerlos de que escriban correctamente. Rara vez no ignoran los comentarios.

Comment: Acaso creen que es facil escribir bien? Acaso creen que el español es una lengua facil? Acaso creen que los OP no se toman personal que los juzguen? No se conviertan en el meta de area 51... Exigir correcciones ortograficas no es buena idea, excluiriamos a buena parte de la sociedad. Eso es lo que quieren?

Comment: De ahora en adelante daré un -1 a cualquier pregunta con horrores como "freezeado", "printear" y similares.

Comment: @CandidMoe esos son anglicismos, no errores ortograficos.

Comment: si te molesta la ortografia y gramatica de un usuario ... no leas sus preguntas o respuesta ...

Comment: A un usuario no se le puede prohibir publicar por tener faltas de ortografia, la solucion sigue siendo que los usuarios mas experimentados editen la pregunta y corrijan los errores, moderacion entre todos con responsabilidad

Answer (score 7):

Antes que nada, comparto totalmente tu preocupación, ahora con respecto a:

> ¿Debería haber más exigencia gramatical y ortográfica?

Pongamos en claro cuales podrían ser los métodos para "exigir", que son aquellos que tienen consecuencias reales para los usuarios:

1. Cierre de una pregunta "Por errores gramaticales y ortográficos"
2. Votar negativamente una pregunta por este mismo motivo

Con el método 1, no contamos con este motivo de cierre. No podemos aplicarlo sin cambiar estos motivos, cosa que veo muy dificultosa de lograr. Con el método 2 estaríamos infringiendo las constitución del sitio y uno de sus valores más importante: votamos la pregunta en función de su utilidad.

Así que desde un punto de vista práctico, hoy no tenemos herramientas para exigir nada al respecto de tu pregunta. Ahora bien, en caso de tener las herramientas:

> ¿Deberíamos implementarlas para exigir más calidad gramatical y
> ortográfica?

opino que NO, por varias razones:

- No lo he visto nunca como política en ningún foro, sitio o red social. Ni siquiera  en medios tradicionales se llega a rechazar, por ejemplo,  una carta de lectores por contener errores ortográficos, eventualmente el editor tomará la decisión de corregirlos, claro, no es un argumento pero mínimamente me hace dudar que sea efectivo implementar algo así.
- Tenemos usuarios, incluso que participan mucho, cuya lengua materna no es el Castellano, y que lógicamente van a cometer errores de todo tipo ¿Tenemos que penalizar sus preguntas por esto? ¿y la gente que ha tenido lamentablemente una educación de baja calidad o incluso tiene algún trastorno o dificultad inherente?
- ¿Y los hispanohablantes que por pereza escriben como si mandaran un SMS? ahí dudo un poco, pero el problema es ¿Cómo los identificamos?
- ¿Y los que simplemente escriben mal, por la época en que vivimos, como dice Candid Moe? bueno, es una pena, coincido, pero creo que la comunidad no está para exigirles esto, para eso debería estar el mundo profesional.

Por otro lado:

- Ya tenemos enormes dificultades para que la gente lea, entienda y siga los lineamientos para construir una buena pregunta. Muchos, de los nuevos y no tan nuevos se enojan, decepcionan y se van, cuando simplemente se les pide algo tan elemental como pegar el código del que están preguntando, sobre esto, agregar una capa más de dificultad para el acceso al sitio, representaría menos preguntas y menos tráfico, y el sitio sobrevive con esto, no me cabe duda que la compañía no tendría ningún problema en cerrarlo si los números no le cierran.
- Por último, entrar en el terreno de la corrección ortográfica y gramatical, sería entrar en un lugar bastante ambiguo, dificultoso y del que no tenemos conocimiento, ¿Cuándo una pregunta es válida en este sentido y cuando no? ¿Si le faltó un acento a una palabra la damos por válida o no?

> ¿Entonces dejamos que la gente escriba como se le ocurra y nos
> olvidamos de la calidad de las preguntas en este sentido?

No, creo que no debería ser así. Escribir razonablemente bien es un atributo de un buen profesional, y este es un sitio de y para profesionales, las preguntas deberían tener un mínimo de calidad en este sentido. Lo único que a mí me cierra y que aplico, es el criterio de actuar como un "Curador" o "Editor" de las preguntas, claramente no puedo hacerlo con todas, lo hago con aquellas que respondo o con las que le veo potencial para trascender en el tiempo, esto es "educar con el ejemplo", algo muy efectivo. Hace muchos años un usuario me corrigió el titulo de una de mis preguntas, simplemente agregando el signo de interrogación de apertura y el acento en un "Cómo hacer tal cosa", desde ese día, lo aplico tanto en mis preguntas como en la de otros usuarios, y puedo confirmar que muchos luego aplican este criterio.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con tu opinión @PatricioMoracho. ;)

Comment: Yo expuse un par de los puntos de esta respuesta y me llovieron negativos...

Comment: ¿y si los del SOes ponen un botón en el editor que sea "Revisar ortografía" que se salte los trozos de código y que marque las palabras dudosas?  Quizás más de uno lo pulsaría y algo ganaríamos.

Comment: Es que eso ya está de alguna manera  implementado a nivel del navegador, al menos el chrome mientras escribo esto, me está señalando las palabras mal escritas (o no encontradas en sus diccionarios), otro tema que tal vez si podría valer la pena es algún tipo de analizador gramatical, tipo lo que implementa el Word, pero me resulta dudoso que se quiera implementar algo así en toda la Red de SO. Habría que investigar un poco si hubo este tipo de discusiones en la red inglesa.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Bueno, en mi caso mi sistema y mi navegador no están en castellano, y conmutar entre un idioma u otro para la revisión de la edición en SOes no me conviene (de hecho lo tengo deshabilitado siempre, pues normalmente hago cosas en 3 idiomas a la vez).  Por eso lo decia a nivel del Editor de SOes.

Comment: No consideré ese puente, es cierto.

Answer (score 3):

Exigir o de alguna forma obligar a realizar preguntas con buena ortografía lo veo muy complicado, yo me pasé buenos meses corrigiendo cuanta pregunta encontraba y la cantidad de estas siempre va creciendo.

Incluso me pasó muchas veces que corregía alguna pregunta y el dueño de ésta la revertía XD arruinando todo el tiempo que pasé corrigiéndola.

Lastimosamente lo que yo veo es que no es posible restringirles esto, ni obligarles a hacer una buena redacción, es como cuando se les intenta obligar a que *agreguen siempre código mínimo verificable en las preguntas* y *que agreguen también explicación en sus respuestas*, simplemente pasan de largo y no le toman importancia.

Comment: Sin embargo, se puede cerrar una pregunta así por incumplir las reglas del sitio que has comentado, ¿me equivoco?. No sería bueno buscar una cohesión ortográfica en las preguntas? 

Evidentemente, puedes tener alguna falta de ortografía o algún error de puntuación que pueda ser editable; pero me refiero a posts que son un despropósito para el lenguaje, a veces incluso incomprensibles.

Comment: Ahh bueno en los casos obviamente extremos en los que la pregunta es incomprensible siempre tenemos la opción "**Necesita detalles o aclaraciones**" cosa que siempre intento aplicar cuando tengo ese tipo de problemas, o simplemente pedirle al usuario que realice una mejor explicación desde los comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

Como persona que escribe en español como lengua nativa, me cuesta muchisimo saber cuando hay que usar tildes, o cuando va una s o una z cuando pareciera que suenan igual.
No hay, o no me enseñaron, reglas ortograficas que me indiquen con 100% de seguridad cuando una palabra lleva tilde. Las que hay son un chiquitin complejas y no engloban todos los casos.
Yo no noto cuando cometo ciertas faltas de ortografía. Lo mismo seguramente les pasa a muchos.
Esto le quitaría oportunidad a mucha gente de poder preguntar en este sitio.

Sin embargo, si las faltas de ortografía hacen de una pregunta inentendible, yo creo que ahí si se debería de exigir que se reescriba.

El mundo no es blanco y negro. Que una pregunta tenga ausencia de tildes, o algún punto que alguien olvidó, debería, para mi, ser perdonado. Pero ciertas faltas de ortografía como la falta de puntos y coma (que hace que la persona parezca "hablar rapido"), y cualquier otra que no nos permita comprender la pregunta, yo creo que esas deberían ser cerradas.

> Algo que me gusta mucho en este sitio es que pude escribir de forma informal y con mi nivel de ortografía (que es un poco bajo) sin que nadie se molestara conmigo. Escribir con mis informalidades es parte de la pasión que siento al escribir una respuesta. Por favor, no cambien eso c:

Comment: Por supuesto que hay reglas que indican con una precisión matemática cuando una palabra va acentuada con tilde o no. También para los usos de `z`, `c` y `s`. Al igual que el código, el español es un lenguaje con normas sintácticas y gramaticales que permiten una compresión más perfecta.

Comment: Conoces algún link a esas reglas? No cuentas las de "las palabras graves se acentuan cuando..." por que esas parecen muy imprecisas. El español es una versión mal hablada del latin, asi que me cuesta confiar en sus reglas sintacticas.

Comment: En la propia RAE se detalla el uso de tildes, que va más allá de "las palabras graves se acentúan cuando...", por supuesto. Las ambiüedades como solo/sólo o aun/aún también se aplican como especiales, al igual que un verbo irregular https://www.rae.es/dpd/tilde

Comment: Ya veo. Si enseñasen eso en primaria, nadie cometería faltas de ortografía. Lamentablemente, es muy tarde para mi...

Comment: En España sí se enseña en primaria, desconozco la situación en otros lugares. No obstante, hoy día y en un foro de programación creo que no hay justificación para cometer muchas de las faltas comunes, debido a la existencia de correctores ortográficos.

Comment: En eso te doy la razón.

Comment: Nunca dije que esté en desacuerdo con pedir o aplicar correcciones ortograficas. Pero exigir? ._. Me sorprende que esta pregunta tenga 3 votos positivos.

Comment: @DanteS. nunca es tarde para aprender, y eso se aplica en cualquier caso :)

Comment: Pues para mi lo es. Es demasiado que aprender...

Comment: @DanteS. Todo es empezar. Al igual que la programación, las lenguas tienen su propia sintaxis y reglas, y si bien no te asusta seguir aprendiendo sobre programación (pues entiendo que al ser miembro activo de esta comunidad sigues aprendiendo cosas, como todos los que participamos), tampoco debería asustarte aprender sobre el idioma.  Otra cosa son las ganas y motivaciones que tengas sobre este tema en cuestión, que ya se aprecia por tus respuestas que son bien pocas, pero no es excusa lo de "es demasiado que aprender" :-)  Todo es ponerse y poco a poco se consigue. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias! En realidad, no estoy motivado para aprender el idioma.